# Converting a Video from 1600 * 1200 to 1200 * 900

Tags: conversion, video-recording, handbrake

I have a video in the format of 1600 * 1200.
I want to convert this video into 1200 * 900.

I have done this with handbrake, but the first 10 seconds of the video is black and scrambled.
Is there a way to convert the video correctly with handbrake or can I do this differently ?

**UPDATE**
When I play the converted video the first time with "Windows Media Player" the first 10 seconds are not visible correct. If I replay the same video in the same "Windows Media Player" session it shows up correctly also the first 10 seconds.

Comment: Try another player such as [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and see if it plays back normally there. Windows Media Player is terrible

Comment: It's the player, not the video.

Answer (score 2):

Use ffmpeg with `-vf scale=1200:900` option. For example

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=1200:900 -c:a copy output.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

I havent used it in ages... but the paid version of Quicktime (I think there still is one - Quicktime Pro; it was about $20) actually had a pretty decent arsenal of rendering options, including scaling, matting, cropping, etc.

It did, at the time a year or two back, a MUCH better job than VLC. Worth the $20, which is a one time fee, and upgrades are free.

Answer (score 0):

The easy but long way is using editing softwares i.e. Import the file and then export it. I will suggest Sony Vegas Pro any version you can use other paid video editing softwares too.

For open source video editing softwares you have: blender

For full featured trial version: NCH videopad (very simple and bad) : I don't recommend it tho.